# visual basic share variable with class?

Tags: vb.net

Please help me to understand how to use class to share variables. 
I have 3 forms and one class to store some variables. Inside form1 I am calling myclass and setting up variables. Now I show form2 and inside form2 I call form3

Is it possible to get variable from a class , which I have sent from first form ?
Myclass code looks like this :

```
    Private _var As String
Public Sub setvar(ByVal var As String)
    _var = pvar
End Sub

Public Function getvar() As String
    Return _var
End Function
```

from form1 :

```
       Public class1 As myclass
      class1 = New myclass
       class1.setvar("test")
```

Now I want to call class1.getvar and I want it return the value which  I have entered in a first form. is it possible ? if yes please help me how ?

Thanks

Comment: This usually goes badly when you say "I call form3".  A core OOP concept is that you *never* call a class.  You call a method.  Seeing the difference is *very* important to get ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have used the 'Public' access modifier on you 'class1' variable definition you should be able to access it as a field on Form1 from anywhere that has access to that instance of Form1.

```
Dim myString as String = form1.class1.getvar()
```

It would probably be neater not to do it this way though.

OPTION1
If it were me I would prefer to create the instance of MyClass in the first form and then pass that instance to the other forms (possibly through the constructor).

```
Public Class Form1

   Private _instance As MyType


   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      _instance = New MyType

      Dim newForm As New Form2(_instance)
   End Sub
```

End Class
Modify the New method of Form2 and Form3 to accept a parameter of type MyClass:

```
Public Class Form2

   Private _instance As MyType

   Sub New(instance As MyType)
      _instance = instance
   End Sub

End Class
```

Then you are passing the variable in when you create the new form and storing it in a private member that you can access anywhere in the code of the second form.

OPTION2
Alternatively, you could put the definition of class1 into a module and then you could access it from wherever you want in the project.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Can you please tell me where to write this code ?  Public Sub New(instance As MyClass) thaks

Comment: I wrote that code to designer file of form . it partly worked               Public Sub New(ByVal instance As myclass)
        InitializeComponent() 
        MsgBox(instance.getvar)
    End Sub                                                                                it works good. gives me correct value. But I want use that getvar from inside of form2 , for example from button click or any other events. How to do it ? Thanks

Comment: create a private member variable of type MyClass in form2 and store the reference (instance) in that. Then you can use it anywhere in form2.

Comment: like this ? private insideformclass as myclass  and                           Public Sub New(ByVal instance As myclass)                         InitializeComponent()                                  MsgBox(instance.getvar)                                                   insideformclass =instance                                         End Sub                                                                             ?

Comment: looks like it is right @SamirMemmedov, I added some more example code to the answer.